# Add reference without VS

Tags: f#

I would like to develop WCF service and open System.ServiceModel.

All works fine if I add reference to System.ServiceModel in my project, but I am just wondering how can I add this reference without VS, in Mac OS, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're compiling with other tools, you can configure them to add `-r <dll-name>` to the compiler command line, or compile from the command line yourself.

See the F# compiler options here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233171.aspx